# How can i correct this anova analysis error?

Tags: r, anova

i'm trying to do an anova analysis on RStudio between a qualitative and a quantitative variable.

```
anova3<-aov(Freq_RTC~Spesa_RTC,data=CCR)
model.tables(anova3,type="mean")
summary(anova3)
etaSquared(anova3)
```

and i keep getting this error:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
> NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In storage.mode(v) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion

I tried to correct it in this way

```
CCR$Freq_RTC <- as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", CCR$Freq_RTC))
CCR$Spesa_RTC <- as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", CCR$Spesa_RTC))
```

but it doesn't work.

can you please help me?

Comment: please provide your dataframe `CCR` so we can reproduce your code

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to point to having na's in your data set. If this is the cause of the problem you could try to remove the na's and run your analysis again.